# Git: apply feature branch using rebase (without merge)

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-rebase

There is a small topic branch that I'd like to apply on top of my main branch. I think the canonical way to do this is:

```
git merge topic-branch
```

But I'd like to have the commits applied one-by-one instead of generating a merge commit.

Naively running `git rebase topic-branch` obviously won't work because it applies my master *onto* the topic branch, as if the topic branch was my upstream. So I tried this:

```
git rebase master topic-branch
```

And this does what I want, except that now I have a detached HEAD, and I need to fix the master branch to point to the HEAD (using `branch -f`). I could of course write a Bash function to do this automatically, but is there a "proper" way to pull in a topic branch without using `merge`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
git checkout topic-branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge topic-branch
```

This solves the problem for a local branch. Solving for a tracking branch is left as an exercise.

EDIT: I suppose I should explain what's going on here. First you change to the topic branch; then you rebase the topic branch so that it is based on master. (Then, of course, you test that everything still works. You *do* have automatic tests, right?) Now that the topic branch is ahead of the master, you can change back to master and merge topic into master; no merge commit is necessary, since it's a fast-forward.

Comment: Yeah, for a tracking branch you'd have to copy it first into a local branch, and then delete it when you're done.  If you wrap the whole thing into a Bash function, it might actually be usable though.

Comment: @Jo Liss no! that misses out the all-important testing step! You should always test after a rebase to ensure you don't merge broken commits into master. This is fundamentally a two-step process: 1. rebase topic and ensure it works; 2. fast-forward master to topic. Trying to make it a one-step process is dangerous because it misses the quality control step of making sure the topic branch works after the rebase.

Comment: Doesn't the same apply for `git merge remote/branch` though?  I'm scarily comfortable testing after the fact (but before I push), and backing off with `rebase --hard origin` if things go wrong.

Comment: @Jo Liss you certainly need to test before you push; it's easier to back out if you test before fastforwarding master, because otherwise you have to look through the reflog to find where to rewind to.

Comment: So wait, can this actually do anything that `cherry-pick` can't?  Because in the cases with merge history that I have on my disk, where `merge topic-branch` succeeds, running `rebase master` fails with the same conflict as `cherry-pick HEAD..topic-branch`.  So I'm wondering, does `rebase` *ever* work where `cherry-pick` doesn't?

Comment: @Jo Liss short answer: no. Long answer: I'd choose this workflow over `cherry-pick` because I prefer not to merge into master until I'm sure that what I'm merging in will work. If the tests fail after `rebase master` (not just if there's a conflict, but also if the functionality is somehow broken as shown by automated tests), then I can fix the problems in `topic-branch` without polluting `master` with broken code. If the same happens using `cherry-pick`, then backing out requires a `reset --hard` and is less intuitive and more error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

I also just figured out that cherry-pick supports commit ranges, so you could do

```
git cherry-pick HEAD..contributor/topic-branch
```

(This successively applies all commits in `topic-branch` that are not reachable from HEAD.)

I get a sense from the man page that this will fail if there are merge commits in the topic branch, so this only works for simple cases with linear history.

Also, if you do this with a local topic branch, `branch -d` will not detect that `topic-branch` was merged, so you'll have to use `-D`.  (Philip's `rebase`+`merge` method by comparison doesn't have this problem.)

Comment: I can confirm this doesn't work with merges, which is a shame. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to port range of commits from `commit-start-id` to `topic-branch-head`, then do

```
git checkout contributor/topic-branch
git rebase --onto master <commit-start-id>
```

Comment: This is a no-op for me (I think because it rebases master onto master).

Comment: Ah, OK.  I'm trying to pull topic-branch *into* master without generating a merge commit, whereas this rebases topic-branch, so I don't think it will solve the problem.  Thanks though!